# Upgrading Asp.net framework 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net

Can i upgrade my existing website from asp.net framework 2.0 to 4.0, is there any harm in doing that? and if i can do that without harming my current website than please tell me the required steps to achieve this target.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this? Want to use features from v4?

Comment: yes, i have to use some of its features.

Comment: It entirely depends on your code and configuration, of which you posted none. Get a test server, deploy your site, change it to .NET 4 and see what happens. Any error you can possibly get already is answered on this site.

Comment: Open your project -> `Alt+Enter` -> `Application` -> `Target Framework` change this

Answer (score 3):

There are [some breaking change if you move to asp.net ver 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes)

Meaning that you may need to change few things, and evaluate all the pages to see that they still working the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I've always updated my projects through using newer versions of Visual Studio. So for example I'd quite a few projects created in VS 2005 which I then opened in VS2010. VS prompted me to upgrade to the newer .net version and took care of the process for me. Never caused any problems although I stopped it from messing with the web.config etc. which it asks about after doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You should have no big issues except for web.config entries specific to .NET 2.0.
On your application server, you may need to set "Classic mode" insted of "Integrated pipeline" if you experience further issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's no harm in trying. There may be some changes required to your code. Just create a copy of your existing code and attempt to upgrade the copy. Based on that, the decision to go forward with an upgrade is up to you.